# Found multiple defaults.yaml resources. Intellj IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-kafka, apache-storm

[t](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEdK3.png)

Found multiple defaults.yaml resources. You're probably bundling the Storm jars with your topology jar.

Comment: This will come when im install android studio

Comment: Incorrect question, no question marks, no description, wrong formatting log code. Please fix it. I bet You can do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a topic here https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000536364-Can-t-start-Intellij-after-update mentioning Your problem.

Please reinstall IntelliJ/Android Studio IDE. It should solve the problem.